# Problem with android ConstraintLayout chained layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've been staring at and checking this for hours.  Its a constant Layout with 4 headings and a RecyclerView.  The headings are 'Task Name', 'Description', 'Date', and 'Duration'.  It's using a Chain Layout (long story but I need to use Chain Layout rather than weight).  In the Degigner and app I only get the first 3 columns displayed.  The last one 'Duration' is not displayed.

[image: app]

The code for the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_name_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_description_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_description_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_description"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_start_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_start_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_date"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_description_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_duration_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_duration"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_start_heading"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/td_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        tools:listitem="@layout/task_duration_items" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the start to the end of the parent - essentially saying put the `TextView` offscreen.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/td_duration_heading"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"/>
```